# traversing div's of the same class

Tags: javascript, html, traversal

i have 5 div's of the same class but different id stacking on top of each other. how do I traverse them using javascript? they are named div1, div2, div3, etc...

also, how do i change each div's attribute while traversing?

thank you very much.

tam.

Comment: For cross browser compatability and speed use jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Both Mootools and JQuery allow usage of all CSS3 selectors, and Mootools selector engine is just a tad faster than Sizzle's - not enough to warrant switching to just for that (though I feel Mootools is easier to use overall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all read this article

[**getElementsByClassName Speed Comparison**](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

and

**[Enhanced getElementsByClassName](http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/js-getelementsbyclassnameex.shtml)**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for ( var i = 0; len = elements.length; i < len; i ++ )
{
    if ( elements[i].className === "yourclassname" )
    {
        // change the desired attribute of element.
        //Eg elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Using jQuery [**each**](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each) function

```
$(".yourclassname").each ( function() {
    // $(this) will fetch the current element
});
```

Comment: Actually I'd say getElementsByTagName would be faster at this.

Comment: @pheonix `document.getElementsByClassName` is FF only

Answer (score 4):

In modern browsers you can get them by using the [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) function:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');

for (var i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
  //..
}
```

Notice that I'm getting the `elements.length` only once, that is a common practice when iterating HTMLCollections.

That's because those collections are "live", they can change at any time, and accessing the length property on each iteration it's expensive.

For complete cross-browser implementations, check this article by Mr. Resig:

- [getElementsByClassName Speed Comparison](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

**Edit:** I leave you here a refactored version of the [Dustin Diaz](http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass/) getElementsByClassName cross-browser pure DOM Implementation:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node,classname) {
  if (node.getElementsByClassName) { // use native implementation if available
    return node.getElementsByClassName(classname);
  } else {
    return (function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node) {
        if ( node == null )
          node = document;
        var classElements = [],
            els = node.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            elsLen = els.length,
            pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)"), i, j;

        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
          if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
              classElements[j] = els[i];
              j++;
          }
        }
        return classElements;
    })(classname, node);
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 For incompatibility: `document.getElementsByClassName` is FF only.

Comment: @Justin: agree, for that I just added a link where multiple cross-browser implementations are discussed.

Comment: By the way, getElementsByClassName() is not FF only, is now natively supported by the most recent versions of Firefox, Safari, and Opera... http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html

Comment: Good to know, -1 +1.  Just out of curiosity, why did you refactor Diaz's implementation and how does it compare as far as performance is concerned?

Comment: @Justin: I refactored to nest the function in the else statement, also stripped out the `tag` argument, that was used to constraint the search to an specific tag, also added the `i` and `j` variables to the var declaration statement, since they were global...

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = 1; i++; i<=5){
    var div = document.getElementById("div" + i);
    //do stuff with div
}
```

Edit: I see you call it "named" div1...div5, you must give id="div1" also for it to work

Answer (score 1):

Are you using anything like Prototype or jQuery?  If so, I highly recommend one of those, as they make traversal quite easy.  For example, with Prototype it would be:

```
$$('.className').each(function(s) {
    //what you want to do
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The library based answers are obvious, but if you're restricted from using them, [here are a couple methods](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) that are more compatible than using Firefox's (new and glorious!) `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of work to hack through, but here is an article on how to enable queryselectorAll even in old browsers:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed

To do this in Mootools or Prototype:

```
 $$('.className').each(function(element, index) {
   //what you want to do
 });
```

In Jquery it is the same sans the double dollar (as posted by others):

```
 $('.className').each(function() {
   //what you want to do
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution:

Set attributes of all divs:

```
$(".yourclassname").attr("attribute","value");
```

Set text content of all divs:

```
$(".yourclassname").text("New content");
```

Set html content of all divs:

```
$(".yourclassname").html("<h1>New content</h1><p>blah blah blah</p>");
```

The jQuery library can be found at http://jquery.com/.